# How to show measures extend from $\mu_0$ isn't unique

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathscr A = \sigma(B)$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $B$ where

$$B = \{ (a,b] \cap \mathbb Q \mid -\infty \leq a \lt b \leq \infty \}$$

And $B$ is an algebra.

Now define a function (per-measure) $\mu_0:B \to [0, \infty]$ that is $\sigma$-additive on its domain and

$$\mu_0(A) =
\begin{cases}
0, & A = \emptyset \\
\infty, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

How do I show measures on $\mathscr A$ that extends $\mu_0$ is not unique?

Do I write down two different measures or use Caratheodory Extension Theorem to show that $\mu_0$ isn't $\sigma$-finite so there are no unique extension.

Answer (score 0):

$$\mu(A) := \begin{cases} 0, & A = \emptyset, \\ \infty, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$ defines a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A})$ and an extension of $\mu_0$. On the other hand, it is not difficult to see that

$$\nu(A) := \begin{cases} \infty, & A \cap \mathbb{Q} \neq \emptyset, \\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

is also a measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A})$ and extends $\mu_0$. This means that there does not exist a unique extension of $\mu_0$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{A})$.